# Calculation preview math

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, preview

in a php page, I have the following Javascript code:

```
<script>
let items = 0;

function addItem() {
  items++;

  let html = "<tr>";
  html += "<td>" + items + "</td>";
  html += "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='itemName[]'></td>";
  html += "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='itemCompany[]'></td>";
  html += "<td style='width:60px;'><input type='text' class='form-control itemQuantity' id='itemQuantity' name='itemQuantity[]'></td>";
  html += "<td style='width:100px;'><input type='text' class='form-control itemPrice' id='itemPrice' name='itemPrice[]'></td>";
  html += "<td style='width:100px;'><input type='text' class='form-control' id='itemAdvance' name='itemAdvance[]'></td>";
  html += "<td style='width:100px;'><input type='text' class='form-control' id='itemDiscount' name='itemDiscount[]'></td>";
  html += "<td style='width:100px;'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='itemRounding[]'></td>";
  html += "<td><input type='text' class='form-control' name='itemNote[]'></td>";
  html += "<td style='text-align:center'><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' onclick='deleteRow(this);'>Delete</button></td>";
  html += "<td><input type='text' readonly name='result' id='result'></td>";
  html += "</tr>";


  let row = document.getElementById("tbody").insertRow();
  row.innerHTML = html;
}

function deleteRow(button) {
  items--
  button.parentElement.parentElement.remove();

}
</script>
```

I used the querySelectotAll and the For loop

to do the calculation I used this script but it doesn't work. How can I make the calculation appear in each row?

```
<script>
let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".inputValue").value;

function myFunction() {

  for (i = 0; i < elements.lenght; i++) {
    let totalPrice = price * quantity;
  }
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = totalPrice.toFixed(2);
}
</script>
```

I tried to loop a math operation

Comment: `elements.lenght` really?

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns a list of elements. The list doesn't have a `.value` property, you have to get that from each element separately.

Comment: In case you missed the point of @LeeTaylor -- you misspelled `length`

Comment: Where do you set the `price` and `quantity` variables inside the `for` loop?

Comment: You have no `class="inputValue` in the HTML. What do you think you're selecting with that call to `querySelectorAll()`?

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. You shouldn't use the same ID in every row of the table. Either assign the IDs dynamically, or leave them out if they're not really needed.

Comment: I corrected the code, added inputValue class in input fields. While the script to loop is this: <script>let elements = document.querySelectorAll(".inputValue");
 
 function myFunction() {
   
  for(i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
   let totalPrice = price * quantity;
  }
  document.getElementById("risultato").innerHTML = totalPrice.toFixed(2);
 }
 </script>